# Why do scala maven artifacts have an artifact for each scala version instead of a classifier per scala version?

Tags: scala, maven, classification

Since you have only source compatibility between [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/)-versions you unfortunately need to compile libraries like [scalatest](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest) or [scalamock](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalamock) for each scala version they support. What puzzles me is that the libraries are provided with loads of artifacts (scalatest_2.9.0, scalatest_2.9.1, scalatest_2.10 and so forth) - one for each scala version, such that the maven repository is littered with many artefacts that are built from the same source. My instinct tells me rather to use one artifact with a classifier for each scala version. (In fact, the [maven pom reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html) mentions that this was sometimes done with jdk14 and jdk15 classifiers for artifacts, which seems similar to me.)  So, why did the Scala people go for the many artifact overkill :-) instead?

Comment: Perhaps it is somewhat related to fact that Scala binaries are not compatible between major versions and shouldn't be mixed.

Comment: It goes well beyond "shouldn't!" You'll generally get an exception when you try to load a class generated by an incompatible version of the compiler. It can also be a rather perplexing error—nothing so straightforward as a "Scala version mis-match; please find a version of the class from a compatible version of the Scala compiler"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may be wrong, but if a classifier's purpose is to "distinguish artifacts that were built from the same POM but differ in their content", then I see a very good reason **not** to use them for scala versioning: scala versions are not just binary incompatible, they can very well be **source incompatible**.
By example, when upgrading scala from 2.7 to 2.8, I had to make some significant changes to the code base. If I wanted to keep both a scala 2.7 and 2.8 version at the same time, I would have needed to create a parallel branch, and both branches would definitely not have the same source code.

When I read "from the same POM", I understand that it means from the same source code too, which would clearly not be the case with those two branches of code.

Another more important reason is that a classifier is essentially a single string, which is already used for many things. More or less standard classifiers include "sources", "javadoc" or "resources". The meanings of these classifiers are the same in scala project, and are totally orthogonal to the scala version, as I'll try to show.

Maven's documentation suggests using classifiers such as "jdk15" or "jdk14" to denote which version of the jvm the binary artifact was compiled against.
Given that java code is backward compatible, in principle the artifacts with both classifiers ("jdk15" or "jdk14") are compiled from the same source code. This is why you don't need to duplicate classifiers for "sources" artifact, or in other words you **don't** need to have a classifier named "sources-jdk14" and "sources-jdk15".
But you cannot apply the same rationale to the scala version: given that you might need different source code whether you compile against scala 2.7 or scala 2.8, you would indeed need two different artifacts with classifiers such as "sources-scala2.7" or "source-scala2.8". So we have composite classifiers already.
As for binary artifacts, you would also not only need to distinguish between the target jvm version (remember, you can compile your scala code to target different jvm versions) but also the scala version it was compiled against. So you would end up with something like "jdk14-scala2.7" or "jdk14-scala2.8" or "jdk15-scala2.7" or "jdk15-scala2.8". Yet another set of composite classifiers.
So the take home message is that the scala version really is a separate way of classifying artifacts, that is totally orthognal to all the existing classifiers. 
Yes, we could really use composite classifiers as above (such as "sources-scala2.7") but then we would not be using standard classifiers, which is confusing enough in itself, but would also require to modify all the tooling around classifiers: what if I use a build tool that has no knowledge of scala (only java) but knows how to automatically publish a "source" artifact? Will I need to modify this build tool so that he knows to publish a "sources-scala2.7" artifact instead? On the other hand, if I encode the scala version in the (base) artifact name and give that to the build tool, everything works as usual and I get a an artifact with the "source" classifier.

All in all, and contrary to immediate intuition, encoding the scala version in the name allows for **better** integration in the existing java build ecosystem.

Comment: True, the source incompatibility is a good point I didn't think about. It still make me wonder why they even create artifacts for several release candidates of the same release, as in scalatest, though.

Comment: As their name suggests, release candidates are just candidates to a stable release, in other words they are juste previews. As such, they have every right to totally break compatibility with previous release candidates, and thus require a separate version (as long as major problems are found with a given release candidate, they just keep fixing it - potentially breaking compatibility with earlier release candidates - until quality is deemed sufficient for an official release).

Answer (score 2):

Scala provides inter-version compatibility of its bytecode output (`.class` files) only across patch-releases (third component of Major.Minor.Patch version spec).

Maven has no place to properly encode this as a first-class property of the artifact, so it has to be encoded by convention in the name.

Sadly...

Comment: Someone may correct me, but I think that's what Maven classfiers ARE for. From http://maven.apache.org/pom.html -> "The classifier allows to distinguish artifacts that were built from the same POM but differ in their content. It is some optional and arbitrary string that - if present - is appended to the artifact name just after the version number." I use version classifiers for my Maven-built scala projects like the one at https://github.com/hohonuuli/scilube